# Protect wordpress wp-login.php permalinks not working (or other way round)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, security, permalinks

I am trying to password protect the wp-login.php file in Wordpress but getting errors.
This is the code that I am adding to the main .htaccess file (obviously the path to the passwd file is correct).

```
# Protect wp-login
<Files wp-login.php>
AuthUserFile "/path/to/my/passwd"
AuthName "Private access"
AuthType Basic
require valid-user
</Files>
```

All works well if Permalinks are off. If I switch off Wordpress Permalinks, then when accessing site.com/wp-login.php redirects in infinite loop and request goes in timeout with the page never displaying.

If I switch on the Permalinks, Worpress adds the directives just after the above block of code that I have posted.

What can be causing this and how can I get this security measure to work along side permalinks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ErrorDocument 401 default
```

as [explained here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/130240/htaccess-in-wp-admin-produces-a-redirect-loop) this was missing from the .htaccess file